# Как заменить значения в колонках DataFrame в зависимости от значений в заданной колонке

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение, анализ-данных

[image: DataFrame]

Создал такой DataFrame. Здесь есть колонка `Cuisine Style`. Для использования в машинном алгоритме мне нужно создать категориальные признаки на основе элементов, которые есть в данной колонке. Сделал. Теперь, мне нужно для этих категориальных признаков проставить значение 1 для тех строк, где в поле `Cuisine Style` есть название колонки из категориальных признаков.

Я использовал код:

```
for l in list_of_cuisune:

    df[l] = df.apply(lambda x: 1 if l in x['Cuisine Style'] else 0, axis = 1)
```

Ранее создал список `list_of_cuisune` и загнал туда все элементы из колонки `Cuisine Style`.

То есть логика такая у меня была: я создал список всех элементов из колонки `Cuisine Style`, на их основе создал новые колонки для новых признаков в датасете. Дальше, я как бы иду по строкам и смотрю - если в `Cuisine Style` есть слово из `list_of_cuisune`, то в соответствующую колонку признака ставлю 1, иначе - оставляю 0.

Код работает, но есть одна проблема - если элемент из списка `list_of_cuisune` (он же признак в датасете) состоит из более, чем одного слова, то оно не хочет корректно сравнивать `l in x['Cuisine Style']` и проставлять 1.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Да, хорошо бы посмотреть примеры какие-то, на каких данных не срабатывает

Comment: Как вариант, удалите пробелы в категории признака и пишите в одно слово, а так да, пока не до конца понятно

Comment: Илья, спасибо. Вы меня натолкнули на поиск ошибки. Действительно, в Cuisine Style я не удалил пробелы, а при создании признаков на основе Cuisine Style  - удалил.

Comment: Ни за что бы не догадался )

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, ваше решение будет работать __очень долго__ на больших датасетах. Мы могли бы посоветовать вам гораздо более эффективное и элегантное решение если бы вы привели в вопросе воспроизводимые примеры данных ;)

Comment: Не знаю как сюда скопировать свой датасет ) Подскажете? ) У меня он на 40 тыс. строк. Да даже как скопировать небольшой фрагмент не знаю.

Comment: @ViktorAndriichuk, проще всего выложить файл на любой не требующий регистрации файлообменник и указать в вопросе ссылку на файл

Comment: @MaxU, пожалуйста, сделал - https://fex.net/ru/s/cnbsy2x (здесь файл ноутбука и датасет). Буду благодарен за комментарии.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
from yaml import safe_load 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer(sparse_output=True)

df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\main_task.csv")    
tmp = df["Cuisine Style"].dropna().apply(safe_load).dropna()

X = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(
        mlb.fit_transform(tmp), 
        columns=mlb.classes_, 
        index=tmp.index)
```

---

результат:

```
In [39]: X
Out[39]:
       Afghani  African  Albanian  American  Arabic  ...  Vietnamese  Welsh  Wine Bar  Xinjiang  Yunnan
0            0        0         0         0       0  ...           0      0         0         0       0
2            0        0         0         0       0  ...           0      0         0         0       0
4            0        0         0         0       0  ...           0      0         0         0       0
6            0        0         0         0       0  ...           0      0         0         0       0
7            0        0         0         0       0  ...           0      0         0         0       0
...        ...      ...       ...       ...     ...  ...         ...    ...       ...       ...     ...
39995        0        0         0         0       0  ...           0      0         0         0       0
39996        0        0         0         1       0  ...           0      0         0         0       0
39997        0        0         0         0       0  ...           0      0         0         0       0
39998        0        0         0         0       0  ...           0      0         0         0       0
39999        0        0         0         0       0  ...           0      0         0         0       0

[30717 rows x 125 columns]
```

можно также объединить получившийся разреженный DataFrame с оригинальным, но при этом он превратиться в обычный (`dense`) DataFrame:

```
res = df.join(X, how="left")
```

---

результат:

```
In [41]: res
Out[41]:
      Restaurant_id       City                            Cuisine Style  Ranking  Rating  ... Vietnamese  Welsh  \
0           id_5569      Paris  ['European', 'French', 'International']   5570.0     3.5  ...        0.0    0.0
1           id_1535  Stockholm                                      NaN   1537.0     4.0  ...        NaN    NaN
2            id_352     London  ['Japanese', 'Sushi', 'Asian', 'Gril...    353.0     4.5  ...        0.0    0.0
3           id_3456     Berlin                                      NaN   3458.0     5.0  ...        NaN    NaN
4            id_615     Munich  ['German', 'Central European', 'Vege...    621.0     4.0  ...        0.0    0.0
...             ...        ...                                      ...      ...     ...  ...        ...    ...
39995        id_499      Milan  ['Italian', 'Vegetarian Friendly', '...    500.0     4.5  ...        0.0    0.0
39996       id_6340      Paris  ['French', 'American', 'Bar', 'Europ...   6341.0     3.5  ...        0.0    0.0
39997       id_1649  Stockholm                    ['Japanese', 'Sushi']   1652.0     4.5  ...        0.0    0.0
39998        id_640     Warsaw  ['Polish', 'European', 'Eastern Euro...    641.0     4.0  ...        0.0    0.0
39999       id_4824      Milan                              ['Spanish']   4827.0     3.0  ...        0.0    0.0

      Wine Bar Xinjiang Yunnan
0          0.0      0.0    0.0
1          NaN      NaN    NaN
2          0.0      0.0    0.0
3          NaN      NaN    NaN
4          0.0      0.0    0.0
...        ...      ...    ...
39995      0.0      0.0    0.0
39996      0.0      0.0    0.0
39997      0.0      0.0    0.0
39998      0.0      0.0    0.0
39999      0.0      0.0    0.0

[40000 rows x 136 columns]
```

Comment: Спасибо. Буду знать как сделать такую штуку быстрее.